# I keep gettin the "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')"

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am connecting to a YouTube API that returns the first results of a search, the problem is that for some reason the src of the image (`video.bestThumbnail.url`), being specific, the `.url` is not being recognized as a property of `bestThumbnail`.

This is the part of the code:

```js
const API = 'https://youtube-search-results.p.rapidapi.com/youtube-search/?q=asyncrhony%2Bin%2Bjavascript'; 

const content = null || document.getElementById('content'); 

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'API key here',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'youtube-search-results.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
};

async function fetchData(urlApi) {
    const response = await fetch(urlApi, options);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data; 
}


(async () => {
    try {
        const videos = await fetchData(API); 
        let view = `
        ${videos.items.map(video => `
        <div class="group relative">
            <div
            class="w-full bg-gray-200 aspect-w-1 aspect-h-1 rounded-md overflow-hidden group-hover:opacity-75 lg:aspect-none">
            <img src="${video.bestThumbnail.url}" alt="${video.description}" class="w-full">
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4 flex justify-between">
            <h3 class="text-sm text-gray-700">
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="absolute inset-0"></span>
                ${video.title}
            </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        `).slice(0, 4).join('')}
        `; 
        content.innerHTML = view;
    } catch (error) { console.log(error); }
})();
```

For example if I change the src to a URL or just `video.bestThumbnail`, it does recognize it as an image but it appears on the page as null or undefined (in the latter case). I'm completely lost.

Comment: Is this a node.js script?

Comment: it is just javascript

Comment: What is unclear about an error message such as _“Cannot read property `url` of `undefined`”_? You can’t read properties of `undefined`, but that’s what happens at `video.bestThumbnail.url` because `video.bestThumbnail` is `undefined`; it’s trying to get `url` off of `undefined` — not possible. You seem to be misinterpreting the error message: it doesn’t say that `video.bestThumbnail.url` _itself_ is `undefined`; this wouldn’t be an error by itself. If you don’t know why `video.bestThumbnail` is `undefined`, use the debugger or look at intermediate values: `console.log(video);`.

Comment: @josé-muñoz You can wrap the whole thing in an if (url) (which will just not give you the error, it probably helps with nothing else) or the better solution, check the API docs, or, if this is copypasta from the API website, than you probably need to check your version.